# Why lists have a \topsep but not a \bottomsep?

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

Most of the time, I like my paragraphs to be a little spaced, setting `\parskip` to 5pt.

However, I would like my lists to be part of the preceding text paragraph, but to have those 5pt from the following paragraph.

They should look like:

```
A paragraph (precedint)

Another paragraph with a list
 * an item
 * another item

Yet another paragraph (following)
```

And not like

```
A paragraph (precedint)

Another paragraph with a list
                                  <I don´t want this space>
 * an item
 * another item

Yet another paragraph (following)
```

As I understand, lists have a `\topsep` that is added both in between previous text and following text, together with `\parskip` and `\partopsep`.

I can´t see how to do force a behavior like "bottomsep", since the distance from preceding text and following text is the same according to LaTeX book and enumitem manual (`\topsep`+`\parskip`[+`\partopsep`]).

Answer (score 3):

I take it that the OP is not actually interested in why there is no `\bottomsep` macro, but rather in how to achieve the spacing issue they face.

As the OP states correctly, `\topsep + \parskip` is added before and after each `itemize`. Using the option `nosep` will remove all vertical spacing, but it will keep the `\parskip` before and after each `itemize`.

What one could do, therefore, is to use the `before` option and add a negative spacing equal to the length of `\parskip` before the list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep % removes all spacing, except for \parskip
, before={\vspace*{-\parskip}} %  
}

\begin{document}

Some text

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
    \item Bye
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello
        \item Bye
    \end{itemize}
    \item Hello
\end{itemize}

Some more text

Even more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution doing this:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep%
, topsep=-5pt%
,after=\newline%
}%
```

Is it the best solution?

Comment: Setting the list at the document level applies therefore to all `itemize` lists. Is that what you want? Also, this doesn't really answer the question in the title: "Why do lists have `\topsep` but no `\bottomsep`?"

Comment: No sorry this is completely wrong: it does not add vertical space it adds a spurious extra "white" line of text latex warns you `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 18--19`  10000 is the _maximum_ level of badness, ie its internal quality check on the output is warning you that this is as bad as it can get,